# Сортировка товаров

Tags: php, sql

Нужно сделать сортировку товаров по возростанию/спаданию цены товара. За вывод товаров отвечает следующий цикл:

```html
<div class="box">
            <?php if(isset($SITE_CONTENT['catalog'])): ?>
              <?php //echo '<pre style="display:none;">'; print_r($SITE_CONTENT['catalog']); echo '</pre>';?>



              <?php foreach ($SITE_CONTENT['catalog'] as $val):?>
              <div class="item"> 
               <?php if ($val['oldprice'] > $val['price'] ) { ?>
           <div class="oldpriceicon">-<?php echo round((1- ($val['price'] / $val['oldprice'] ) ) * 100); ?>%</div>
       <?php } ?>
                <?php //echo '<pre style="display:none;">'; print_r($val['oldprice'] ); echo '</pre>';?>
                <?php // echo '<pre style="display:none;">'; print_r($val['price'] ); echo '</pre>';?>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('product/'.$val['link']); ?>" class="image">
                  <?php if(isset($val['image_hover']) && !empty($val['image_hover'])): ?>

     <img  class="hover_image" src="<?php echo baseurl($val['image']); ?>" src-default="<?php echo baseurl($val['image']); ?>" src-hover="<?php echo baseurl($val['image_hover']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $val['name']; ?>" />
   <?php else:?>
     <img  src="<?php echo baseurl($val['image']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $val['name']; ?>" />
   <?php endif;?>
                </a>

                <div class="name">
                  <a href="<?php echo site_url('product/'.$val['link']); ?>" class="link"><?php echo $val['name']; ?></a>
                </div><!-- end .name -->

                <div class="price"><?php if ($val['oldprice'] > $val['price'] ) { ?><span class="oldprice"><?php echo $val['oldprice'].' '.lang('site_valuta'); ?></span><?php } ?><?php echo $val['price'].' '.lang('site_valuta'); ?> </div>
              </div>
              <?php endforeach; ?>


            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

Может кто обьяснить как сделать сортировку?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php

Comment: Какие именно значения нужно подставлять в usort()?